# Getting fragment width 0 in onStart()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

We are using fragment compatibility library, and are trying to get width of the fragment, added to FrameLayout. According to fragment lifecycle, until onCreateView is executed, getView().getMeasuredWidth() should return 0. However, we are getting 0 in onStart(), which comes after onCreateView, and therefore, the returned value should not be 0.

This is fragment which width we want to know:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/carbon_fiber"/>
```

Why this anomaly is happening? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: IMO this is the most frustrating and non-intuitive part of Android. There are many many posts on SO about this. You'd think that the Google team would add a callback on Activity/Fragment for this, something like `yourFrigginViewsHaveDimensionsNow()` would be good.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Activities, the views in the view hierarchy haven't been measured at Fragment::onStart().  To get the size of the view, you need to create an OnGlobalLayoutListener and use it in the following manner:

[Android get Fragment width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845197/android-get-fragment-width)

Answer (score 1):

It's just an assumption, but according to [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle):

> onStart() makes the fragment visible to the user (based on its containing activity being started).

So width and height will be calculated only **after** your fragment will become visible.

But, maybe, I'm not right.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with an Activity. I needed one of my images to maintain a 4:6 ratio. So as simple as I could find for fragments I put the code in its OnStart() for Activities it was the OnWindowFocusChanged()

From researching this it turns out it's because the layout has not actually "drawn" yet. So therefore no components have been measured. There are various other work around but this seemed to me to be the quickest implementations.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I used the post() method of the View class:

```
getView().post( new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    //do your measurements here
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to define the `android:class` with the class of your fragment.