# Getting width and height for ImageView created programmatically

Tags: android, imageview

I am using the ImageMap widget over at [CatchtheCows](http://catchthecows.com/?p=113). This widget (which extends imageView) assumes image and map resources will be stored in res/ folder and thus sets them on the layout xml.

I want to use my own resources stored in the sdcard. So I created a constructor that receives both the map file path and the image file path.

The problem comes because this widget needs the width and height of the imageView to be precalculated in order to scale the bitmap accordingly. But adding the imageView programmatically does not seem to fire the onSizeChanged event.

How can I work around this problem?

This is how I create my ImageMap:

```
mImageMap = new ImageMap(getApplicationContext(),"maps.xml", "/sdcard/media/myimage.jpg");
setContentView(mImageMap, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

and this is the aforementioned constructor:

```
public ImageMap(Context context, String mapFile, String imageFile) {
        super(context);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile);
        this.setImageBitmap(b);

        init();     
        loadMapFromSDCard("maps.xml");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to get the size of the `ImageView` before it is actually rendered, which will return zero. The View size is defined only after being rendered.

[addOnGlobalLayoutListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845197/android-get-fragment-width) might solve your problem, so you only get the size after the render
 is complete

Comment: So in the case of xml definition, does the imageview get actually rendered before calling the constructor?